# Format JSON collection string by JavaScript or Linq

Tags: javascript, linq

Need help to format my JSON collection sting by Javascript or linq

Suppose on page, displaying data for calendar day 1 to 5.

My JSON string looks like below:

```
[
    {“studName”:”aaa”,”class”:”5”,”commentsDay”:”1”},
    {“studName”:”aaa”,”class”:”5”,”commentsDay”:”4”},
    {“studName”:”aaa”,”class”:”5”,”commentsDay”:”1”},
    {“studName”:”aaa”,”class”:”5”,”commentsDay”:”4”},
    {“studName”:”bbb”,”class”:”5”,”commentsDay”:”1”},
    {“studName”:”ccc”,”class”:”6”,”commentsDay”:”3”},
    {“studName”:”ddd”,”class”:”6”,”commentsDay”:”1”},
    {“studName”:”ddd”,”class”:”6”,”commentsDay”:”3”},
    {“studName”:”ddd”,”class”:”6”,”commentsDay”:”2”},
    {“studName”:”ddd”,”class”:”6”,”commentsDay”:”1”} 
]
```

And want it as per format shown below:
{“StudentName”, “Class”, “TotalComments” ,”CommentDetails”}

So my above mention collection string should format like below:

```
[
    {“studName”:”aaa”,”class”:”5”,”TotalComments”:”4”,”Details”:”2,0,0,2,0”},
    {“studName”:”bbb”,”class”:”5”,”TotalComments”:”1”,”Details”:”1,0,0,0,0”},
    {“studName”:”ccc”,”class”:”6”,”TotalComments”:”1”,”Details”:”0,0,1,0,0”},
    {“studName”:”ddd”,”class”:”6”,”TotalComments”:”4”,”Details”:”2,1,1,0,0”}
]
```

Want to display it like below:

```
Name | Total | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

Class 5 //displaying all class 5 data 

aaa  |  4    | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |  
bbb  |  1    | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  

Class 6 //displaying all class 6 data

ccc  |  1    | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  
ddd  |  4    | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
```

Do not understand how to write a loop on original collection string to display data on page like above.

So I tried to modify original collection string in different format (as mention above by using JavaScript), but not succeeded.

Kindly guide.

Thanks in advance.

Vikas

Comment: Looks like a job for [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the array and build new objects with the wanted properties.

The stringified results makes a bit complicated to maintain.

```js
var data = [{ studName: 'aaa', class: '5', commentsDay: '1' }, { studName: 'aaa', class: '5', commentsDay: '4' }, { studName: 'aaa', class: '5', commentsDay: '1' }, { studName: 'aaa', class: '5', commentsDay: '4' }, { studName: 'bbb', class: '5', commentsDay: '1' }, { studName: 'ccc', class: '6', commentsDay: '3' }, { studName: 'ddd', class: '6', commentsDay: '1' }, { studName: 'ddd', class: '6', commentsDay: '3' }, { studName: 'ddd', class: '6', commentsDay: '2' }, { studName: 'ddd', class: '6', commentsDay: '1' }],
    result = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            var temp;
            if (!hash[a.studName]) {
                hash[a.studName] = { studName: a.studName, class: a.class, TotalComments: '0', Details: '0,0,0,0,0' },
                r.push(hash[a.studName]);
            }
            temp = hash[a.studName].Details.split(',');
            temp[a.commentsDay - 1] = +temp[a.commentsDay - 1] + 1;
            hash[a.studName].Details = temp.join();
            hash[a.studName].TotalComments = (+hash[a.studName].TotalComments + 1).toString();
            return r;
        }
    }(Object.create(null)), []);
 
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With post collecting process for strings.

```js
var data = [{ studName: 'aaa', class: '5', commentsDay: '1' }, { studName: 'aaa', class: '5', commentsDay: '4' }, { studName: 'aaa', class: '5', commentsDay: '1' }, { studName: 'aaa', class: '5', commentsDay: '4' }, { studName: 'bbb', class: '5', commentsDay: '1' }, { studName: 'ccc', class: '6', commentsDay: '3' }, { studName: 'ddd', class: '6', commentsDay: '1' }, { studName: 'ddd', class: '6', commentsDay: '3' }, { studName: 'ddd', class: '6', commentsDay: '2' }, { studName: 'ddd', class: '6', commentsDay: '1' }],
    detailsLength = 5;
    result = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (!hash[a.studName]) {
                hash[a.studName] = {
                    studName: a.studName,
                    class: a.class,
                    TotalComments: 0,
                    Details: Array.apply(null, { length: detailsLength }).map(function () { return 0; })
                },
                r.push(hash[a.studName]);
            }
            hash[a.studName].TotalComments++;
            hash[a.studName].Details[a.commentsDay - 1]++;
            return r;
        }
    }(Object.create(null)), []);
 
result.forEach(function (a) {
    a.TotalComments= a.TotalComments.toString();
    a.Details = a.Details.join();
});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think it might be easier to maintain with the details in an array, and then take a second pass with `join(',')` for the stringification.

Comment: Thanks Nina, you given me desired output. Actually I am studying/try to understand it. Is their any other way? I mean, by using "filter" function (instead of reduce) can we achieve the same output or same tabular format? Thanks.

Comment: actually no, because of filter returns the same items, but possibly less according to the return value.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Will study little more and implement it. Thanks one more time.

Comment: Nina, in my previous example I assume data for period between 1 to 5. If that change, How I will manage that. I tried to  make Details array as empty but that not works. eg. Details:[ ] Details array should handle any days data  between 1 to 31. Could you please guide?

Comment: you could give in the second example the length of `Details` with `detailsLength = 5;` or set it to `31`

Comment: Hi Nina, as I informed you earlier, I got solution for my problem. But last few days I tried to understand how JavaScript reduce works exactly (in given solution and overall) but not succeeded. Could you pls guide me or provide me few links/sites where from I can study it again. Thanks.

Comment: you might have a look here: [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)